# PHP mail adds leading newline when no additional headers present

Tags: newline, php

I have encountered some odd behaviour using `mail` on PHP 5.4.17 on Mac OS X Mavericks. When I send a simple e-mail like this:

```
mail("me@example.com", "Test", "A line of text.");
```

the resulting e-mail contains a leading newline. I.e. the source looks like this:

```
(Other headers)
To: me@example.com
Subject: Test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 501:-
Message-Id: ...
Date: Mon, 30 Dec 2013 14:52:49 +1300 (NZDT)
From: me@mymachine.local (Me)


A line of text.
```

However when I add an additional header (such as CC) to the command, the leading newline disappears:

```
mail("me@example.com", "Test", "A line of text.", "Cc: me@example.com\r\n");
```

results in:

```
(Other headers)
To: me@example.com
Subject: Test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 501:-
Cc: me@example.com
Message-Id: ...
Date: Mon, 30 Dec 2013 14:53:33 +1300 (NZDT)
From: me@mymachine.local (Me)

A line of text.
```

How can I get the first line to not add this leading newline? I have tried passing `NULL` and `""` as the `$headers` parameter to `mail` but this has no effect.

Comment: Confirmed on 5.5.7 on Linux with sendmail 8.14.7. I would probably file this as a bug.

Comment: Although I've worked with `mail()` a lot, I've never noticed this since I can't recall ever building production code without at least an additional `X-Mailer` header or the like.

Comment: Ok, looks like the easiest solution is to just add a header. In this case I've just added `From` as an explicit header and that works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "bug" is due to how PHP handles the `X-PHP-Originating-Script` header which is injected when [`mail.add_x_header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.add-x-header) is used; when no custom headers are specified, it will append an extra newline, as can be seen in [the source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/mail.c#279).

You can prevent this issue by disabling the header:

```
ini_set('mail.add_x_header', 0);
```

Or change the respective `php.ini` setting for the change to be effected globally.

**Update**

A fix has been committed to [5.4](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=79b3c2a744e68c61ccfe36df097bdbdfe6e7ff48), [5.5](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=d022c8565da4ec079cd285b245fd28e3f31a3cdb) and [5.6](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=43ac0ab67314b5b448843d6e6ad2824c8ebf133d).